# including parameters in OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, parameters, openquery

How can I use a parameter inside sql openquery, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([NameOfLinkedSERVER], 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
where field1=@someParameter') T1 INNER JOIN MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME
T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK
```

Comment: A workaround is create a view with the openquery and then using the view in the join

Answer (score 187, accepted):

From the [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) documentation it states that:

> OPENQUERY does not accept variables
>   for its arguments.

See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314520) for a workaround.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I'm including the recommendations from the article below.

**Pass Basic Values**

When the basic Transact-SQL statement is known, but you have to pass in one or more specific values, use code that is similar to the following sample:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)
SELECT  @VAR = 'CA'
SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

**Pass the Whole Query**

When you have to pass in the whole Transact-SQL query or the name of the linked server (or both), use code that is similar to the following sample:

```
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000), @TSQL nvarchar(4000), @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)
SET @LinkedServer = 'MyLinkedServer'
SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT au_lname, au_id FROM pubs..authors'')' 
EXEC (@OPENQUERY+@TSQL)
```

**Use the Sp_executesql Stored Procedure**

To avoid the multi-layered quotes, use code that is similar to the following sample:

```
DECLARE @VAR char(2)
SELECT  @VAR = 'CA'
EXEC MyLinkedServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql
N'SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = @state',
N'@state char(2)',
@VAR
```

Comment: Using any of these examples, how do you retrieve the records returned from the exec command?

Comment: To retrieve records, I've always built a table variable or temp table of my result set, then used `INSERT INTO @TableVariable EXEC sp_executeSql @TSQL`

Comment: @JamesChen, it's easiest to think about when you work backwards. Start with the OpenQuery's query: `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col = 'Y'`. To pass that statement as a string to OpenQuery, all single quotes need escaped: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Server, 'SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col = ''Y'' ')`. Then, to pass the SELECT using OpenQuery to Dynamic SQL, THOSE quotes must be escaped: `EXEC sp_executeSQL 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Server, ''SELECT * FROM tab WHERE col = ''''Y'''' '')'`. Hope this helps!

Comment: (can't use @ in the comments so using 'at') Dynamic DAX with params... I prepared the DAX string but Openquery didn't work. Pass the Whole Query method worked. Ran my DAX through this: SET atDAX = REPLACE(atDAX, '''', '''''')  and at the end I had to close the string off and add a final bracket... EXEC (atOPENQUERY + atDAX + '''' + ')')

Comment: @TDP you could, if you formatted the inline code as inline code (using backticks): `SET @DAX = REPLACE(@DAX, '''', '''''')`

Comment: Bret why are you firing OPENQUERY via sp_executesql? Isn't it that you can either use OPENQUERY or use sp_executesql?

Answer (score 20):

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx):

> OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments

Fundamentally, this means you cannot issue a dynamic query. To achieve what your sample is attempting, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   OPENQUERY([NameOfLinkedSERVER], 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME') T1 
   INNER JOIN 
   MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK 
where
   T1.field1 = @someParameter
```

Clearly if your TABLENAME table contains a large amount of data, this will go across the network too and performance might be poor. On the other hand, for a small amount of data, this works well and avoids the dynamic sql construction overheads (sql injection, escaping quotes) that an `exec` approach might require.

Comment: this pointed me down the right path to succeed in what I was trying to accomplish!  Thank you!   this should have more upvotes

Answer (score 17):

You can execute a string with OPENQUERY once you build it up.  If you go this route think about security and take care not to concatenate user-entered text into your SQL!

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(8000)
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Field1 < ''someVal'' AND Field2 IN '+ @valueList 
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SVRNAME, ''' + REPLACE(@Sql, '''', '''''') + ''')'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, if you want to use OpenQuery in context with `if`, for example in `if (SELECT Col1 FROM OPENQUERY('Select ...') > 0 ) BEGIN ... END`

Comment: @Stefan - you can select from openquery and insert the results into a temporary table. From there your options open up a lot, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, We found a way to do this:

```
DECLARE @username varchar(50)
SET @username = 'username'
DECLARE @Output as numeric(18,4)
DECLARE @OpenSelect As nvarchar(500)
SET @OpenSelect = '(SELECT @Output = CAST((CAST(pwdLastSet As bigint) / 864000000000) As numeric(18,4)) FROM OpenQuery (ADSI,''SELECT pwdLastSet
                                FROM  ''''LDAP://domain.net.intra/DC=domain,DC=net,DC=intra''''
                                WHERE objectClass =  ''''User'''' AND sAMAccountName = ''''' + @username + '''''
                          '') AS tblADSI)'
EXEC sp_executesql @OpenSelect, N'@Output numeric(18,4) out', @Output out
SELECT @Output As Outputs
```

This will assign the result of the OpenQuery execution, in the variable @Output.

We tested for Store procedure in MSSQL 2012, but should work with MSSQL 2008+.

Microsoft Says that sp_executesql(Transact-SQL): Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Windows Azure SQL Database (Initial release through current release). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: This only works for Scalar output.  Try Xml or a Table variable and this is not going to work.

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @guid varchar(36);  select @guid= convert(varchar(36), NEWID() );
/*
    The one caveat to this technique is that ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp should ALWAYS have the exact same columns.  
    So make up your global temp table name in the sproc you're using it in and only there!
    In this example I wanted to pass in the name of a global temporary table dynamically.  I have 1 procedure dropping 
    off temporary data in whatever @TableSrc is and another procedure picking it up but we are dynamically passing 
    in the name of our pickup table as a parameter for OPENQUERY.
*/
IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp' , 'U') IS NULL )
    EXEC ('SELECT * INTO ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp FROM OPENQUERY(loopback, ''Select *,''''' +  @guid +''''' as tempid FROM ' + @TableSrc + ''')')
ELSE 
    EXEC ('INSERT ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(loopback, ''Select *,''''' +  @guid +''''' as tempid FROM ' + @TableSrc + ''')')

--If this proc is run frequently we could run into race conditions, that's why we are adding a guid and only deleting
--the data we added to ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp
SELECT * INTO #TableSrc FROM ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp WHERE tempid = @guid

BEGIN TRAN t1
    IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp' , 'U') IS NOT NULL ) 
    BEGIN
        -- Here we wipe out our left overs if there if everyones done eating the data
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp) = 0
            DROP TABLE ##ContextSpecificGlobal__Temp
    END
COMMIT TRAN t1

-- YEAH! Now I can use the data from my openquery without wrapping the whole !$#@$@ thing in a string.
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `execute` method instead of `openquery`. Its code is much cleaner. I had to get `linked server` query result in a variable. I used following code.

```
CREATE TABLE #selected_store
(
   code VARCHAR(250),
   id INT
)
declare @storeId as integer = 25
insert into #selected_store (id, code) execute('SELECT store_id, code from quickstartproductionnew.store where store_id = ?', @storeId) at [MYSQL]  

declare @code as varchar(100)
select @code = code from #selected_store
select @code
drop table #selected_store
```

**Note:**

> if your query doesn't work, please make sure `remote proc transaction
>   promotion` is set as `false` for your `linked server` connection.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
       @server = N'{linked server name}',
       @optname = N'remote proc transaction promotion',
       @optvalue = N'false';
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine Dynamic SQL with OpenQuery. (This goes to a Teradata server)

```
DECLARE 
    @dayOfWk    TINYINT = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()),
    @qSQL       NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @qSQL = '
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENQUERY(TERASERVER,''
        SELECT DISTINCT
            CASE
                WHEN ' + CAST(@dayOfWk AS NCHAR(1)) + ' = 2
                THEN ''''Monday''''
                ELSE ''''Not Monday''''
            END
        '');';

EXEC sp_executesql @qSQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following example I'm passing a department parameter to a stored procedure(spIncreaseTotalsRpt) and  at the same time I'm creating a temp table all from an OPENQUERY.
The Temp table needs to be a global Temp (##) so it can be referenced outside it's intance. 
By using exec sp_executesql you can pass the department parameter.

Note: be careful when using sp_executeSQL. Also your admin might not have this option available to you.

Hope this helps someone.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Temp') IS NOT NULL
/*Then it exists*/
    begin
       DROP TABLE ##Temp
    end 
 Declare @Dept as nvarchar(20) ='''47'''

 declare @OPENQUERY  as nvarchar(max)
set @OPENQUERY = 'Select ' + @Dept + ' AS Dept,  * into ##Temp from openquery(SQL_AWSPROD01,''' 

declare @sql nvarchar(max)= @openquery +  'SET FMTONLY OFF EXECUTE SalaryCompensation.dbo.spIncreaseTotalsRpts ' + '''' + @Dept + ''''  + ''')'
declare @parmdef nvarchar(25) 
DECLARE @param nvarchar(20) 

SET @parmdef = N'@Dept varchar(20)'
-- select @sql
-- Print @sql + @parmdef  + @dept
exec sp_executesql @sql,@parmdef, @Dept  
Select * from ##Temp
```

Results

Dept    increase Cnt    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
        0.0000  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT field1 FROM OPENQUERY 
                   ([NameOfLinkedSERVER], 
                   'SELECT field1 FROM TABLENAME') 
                           WHERE field1=@someParameter T1 
                                 INNER JOIN MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME           
                                 T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK
```

Comment: This code needs a warning that 
A) field1 for *ALL* rows of TABLENAME will be passed across from the linked server - a potentially very expensive operation.
B) the INNER JOIN could also be 'very expensive'

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works for me. It does require the use of a scratch table that a **linked server** has access to though.

I created a table and populated it with the values I need then I reference that table through a linked server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(KHSSQLODSPRD,'SELECT *
  FROM ABC.dbo.CLAIM A WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE A.DOS >= (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM KHSDASQL01.DA_MAIN.[dbo].[ALLFILENAMES]) ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @usernames NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @usernames = N'';
DECLARE @len INT;
SELECT @usernames = @usernames + ISNULL(username + ''''',''''', '')
FROM #tempusername;
SET @len = len(@usernames);
SET @usernames = N'''''' + LEFT(@usernames, @len - 3);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql
= N'SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY
     ([Linked Server],
      ''SELECT username  
       FROM [MySQL Database].[Table Name]
       WHERE username IN ( ' + @usernames + N')'')';
```

I found this workaround on this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98e0c17a-8ead-4633-a053-51c49b313bd3/how-can-i-use-a-table-variable-as-a-parameter-for-openquery?forum=sqltools&prof=required
it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX); 

SELECT @qry=concat('select * from openquery(nube,',char(39),'call DATABASE.STORE_PROCEDURE(',@year,',',@month,',',@day,',"',@place,'")',char(39),')');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry;
```

be sure that create before the params

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @p_Id varchar(10)
SET @p_Id = '40381'

EXECUTE ('BEGIN update TableName
                set     ColumnName1 = null,
                        ColumnName2 = null,
                        ColumnName3 = null,
                        ColumnName4 = null
                 where   PERSONID = '+ @p_Id +'; END;') AT [linked_Server_Name]
```

Comment: Keyword is openquery dude :)

Comment: it is an alternate approach. Whoever knows `openquery` should know this approach as well. It is also much cleaner. So +1 from my side.

Answer (score -1):

Just try it this way, should work, easy! In your WHERE clause, after column name and equal to sign:- add TWO single quotes, your search value and then THREE single quotes. Close the bracket.

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([NameOfLinkedSERVER], 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where field1=''your search value''') T1 INNER JOIN MYSQLSERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLENAME T2 ON T1.PK = T2.PK`

Comment: Your answer uses literal SQL, but the OP wants to use a parameter (note his/her reference to `field1=@someParameter`).

Answer (score -2):

Simple example based off of @Tuan Zaidi's example above which seemed the easiest. Didn't know you can do the filter on the outside of OPENQUERY... so much easier!

However in my case I needed to stuff it in a variable so I created an additional Sub Query Level to return a single value.

```
SET @SFID = (SELECT T.Id FROM (SELECT Id,  Contact_ID_SQL__c  FROM OPENQUERY([TR-SF-PROD], 'SELECT Id,  Contact_ID_SQL__c FROM Contact') WHERE Contact_ID_SQL__c = @ContactID) T)
```