# Passing sql parameter to openquery's query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have following SQL query in SQL Server 2008

```
Select * from
    (Select T.Col1, T.Col2 
     from openquery('server','select * from table 1 where date= '+ @StartDate +') R
```

Where `@StartDate` is a parameter. I get an error that incorrect syntax near '+' expecting ')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate post.

The short answer is OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments. See: [including parameters in OPENQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery) for a possible workaround.