# Java PreparedStatement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException, index out of range

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a `SQL` query using a Java `PreparedStatement` in Java 7 using the code below:

```
PreparedStatement functionalCRsStatement = con.prepareStatement(
    "select * from openquery(SERVER,\n" +
    "\t'Select X , Y, Z,  A from  D r\n" +
    "\tINNER JOIN E c\n" +
    "\tON r.RNID = c.RNID\n" +
    "\twhere  c.Y = ?')\n");

functionalCRsStatement.setString(2, x);
```

I get the following error message: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range.`

PS: I'm sure of the correctness of the SQL query because I successfully tested it without a `PreparedStatement`, I just replaced the real name of the columns in the query by fake ones (X, Y, Z) to hide potentially confidential information.

**EDIT**: I get a similar error when using `setString(1, x)` => `index 1 is out of range`

Comment: You're trying to set the value of the second parameter but you only have one parameter that needs to be set. Also, what's the purpose of `st`? You don't appear to do anything with it. You also don't need to 'prettify' the SQL inside a prepared statement - make it easy to read from the point of view of your code instead of littering the query string with superfluous tab and newline characters.

Comment: `index 2 is out of range` explains it. You should use `1` instead.

Comment: I actually tried `1` first and I get the same erroer `index 1 out of range`

Comment: With that update, it's quite probably down to the fact that the `?` is inside a quoted string, so the API doesn't see it as a placeholder.

Comment: There it is because you are selecting `*` .... Do you need all?

Comment: Do you really need to use openquery for this?

Comment: what value you are going to pass in x ?

Answer (score 4):

As @JonK commented, you have apostrophes in your query, which means your parameter is actually inside a string where the SQL engine won't bind a value (whether you use 1 or 2 as the index):

```
PreparedStatement functionalCRsStatement = con.prepareStatement(
    "select * from openquery(APRPRD,\n" +
    "\t'Select X , Y, Z,  A from  D r\n" +
    "\tINNER JOIN E c\n" +
    "\tON r.RNID = c.RNID\n" +
    "\twhere  c.Y = ?')\n");
```

contains this query (with SQL syntax highlighting, which shows the whole string)

```
select * from openquery(APRPRD,
        'Select X , Y, Z,  A from  D r
        INNER JOIN E c
        ON r.RNID = c.RNID
        where  c.Y = ?')
```

A SQL engine never inspects the inside of a string. How would you insert a string containing a question mark otherwise?

Comment: So you're saying there is no solution?

Comment: If you provide the query as a string, it has to be complete: you have to concatenate the value, which means managing the quotes of the string parameter, etc. Tricky depending on where the string comes from. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3378496/1350869).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only have one `?` in your statement, so you can't make a reference to the second index (2) in the `functionalCRsStatement.setString(2, x);`, because as it says, it's out of range.

you should use

```
 functionalCRsStatement.setString(1, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only one bind variable placeholder (`?`) in your query - so you should bind it with an index of `1`, not `2`:

```
functionalCRsStatement.setString(1, x); // Was 2 in the OP
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one parameter to set in your prepared statement. the set method to set parameter in prepared statement checks index of the `?` in the prepared statement and sets the value to prepared statement accordingly.

So in your case there is only 1 `?` so in an array of values to be passed for prepared statement is 1. and you are trying to pass the value at the index 2 hence it says The

> index 2 is out of range.

Try the same with index 1. as you have only 1 parameter to be set.

e.g. **functionalCRsStatement.setString(1, x);**

remember the value x will be stored to the `?` at 1st index in the prepared statement.

**EDIT** : Also remember the type to the value to be passed. if you are setting value of X as int you need to call setInt(1,x). in this case it will not able to find first index os String and throw an error of index out of range.

Comment: There is already EDIT in question about that he have a same error with `setString(1, x)`

Comment: what is the value of x ?

Comment: It is not my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

The prepared statement is not recognizing any param, for is this query contains 0 params because of mal-written string; try this :

```
PreparedStatement functionalCRsStatement = con.prepareStatement(
    "select * from openquery(APRPRD," +
    "'Select X , Y, Z,  A from  D r" +
    "INNER JOIN E c" +
    "ON r.RNID = c.RNID ')" +
    "where  c.Y = ?");
```