# SQL query with loop to collect 14 day averages

Tags: sql, loops

I am a python user, new to SQL. I am trying to make a new table that is the average of the "NumberValue" column between two dates from "RecordDate" column, and slide that date range so that the new table has columns "average" that is the average of "NumberValue" over the date range, "start_date" that is the beginning of the range, and "end_date" that is the end of the range. I can do this for a single date range at a time with something like:

```
SELECT AVG(NumberValue) AS average, DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()) AS start_date, DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) AS end_date
FROM ResultsData
WHERE RecordDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
```

but would like to slide the -14 and 0 with some sort of loop. Something like looping over the expression below with `i` and `j` changing by -14 each iteration and appending the new row each iteration:

```
SELECT AVG(NumberValue) AS average, DATEADD(DAY, i, GETDATE()) AS start_date, DATEADD(DAY, j, GETDATE()) AS end_date
FROM ResultsData
WHERE RecordDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, i, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, j, GETDATE())
```

I'd also like to make sure the date ranges are within what is available in the table, I'm assuming I can do this with some sort of a `WHILE RecordDate > MIN(RecordDate)` inside the loop?

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: Is this in MySQL, PostgreSQL, T-SQL, or something else?

Comment: @Albert The query will ultimately run in thingworx using the MSSqlServer template

Comment: @GoldenLion I haven't done this in python yet as it will have to run in thingworx, I'm stuck with SQL and/or a loop in JavaScript calling the static version of the SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what worked in the end:

```
SELECT A.start_date, AVG(A.NumberValue) FROM
(SELECT *, DATEADD(dd, -14, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(RecordDate), DAY(RecordDate))) as start_date FROM ResultData) A
GROUP BY A.start_date
ORDER BY A.start_date
```

credit goes to a coworker.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the over window to create a look back.  The over uses the current row then averages 14 preceding rows of data for price.  you can use matplotlib.pyplot to see the moving average against the actual data.

the range window will average by date accumulatively.  The moving average does not change until the date changes.

```
select *,
  IsNull(avg(Price) OVER(ORDER BY Date
     ROWS BETWEEN 14 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ),0)
     as moving_average
from stock_price;


try range



SELECT 
      cast([date] as date) as date
      ,[price]
      ,IsNull(avg([price]) over (order by cast([date]  as date)
      RANGE BETWEEN
          unbounded preceding and current row
      ),0) moving_average
  FROM stock_price
```

Comment: `select *,
  avg(NumberValue) OVER(ORDER BY RecordDate
     ROWS BETWEEN 14 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
     as moving_average
from ResultData;`
This gives the error "The index 1 is out of range"

Comment: same exception: "Execute Query Failed: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range"

Comment: run the query in ssm and see if you get any data.  index 1 out of range means no data

Comment: see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655215/java-preparedstatement-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-index-o) remove the *, and run again.  look for apostrophs in your data

Comment: see (https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5256457/Com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-th)  problems with parameterization

Comment: there is definitely data, my simple query above works just returns the single row

Comment: the bigger problem with this is that there is more than one row per date, the condition needs to be a date range not just 14 rows

Comment: @tcasey: Change `ROWS` to `RANGE` to look at 14 dates rather than 14 rows.

Comment: 14 preceding plus current row is 15 months.

Comment: Still same exception. I don't think there is any issue with the data type or the data being there, my simple query I started with doesn't error no matter what range I put in manually. Maybe i'm not understanding but with `RANGE` on a datetime column to select 14 day periods I'd need to define the start and end dates of the `RANGE`, not just some number of preceding rows. Then i'm back to square one defining the starts and ends. I need an iterator where the start and end of the `BETWEEN` are shifting by 14 days per iteration.

Comment: `RANGE` does exactly that. It considers all rows with the same sortkey - the date in your case - one block. You look back 14 blocks, which means 14 dates.

Comment: Have you tried running directly from a query tool?

Comment: in the end it was much simpler than I was making it, a coworker provided the answer I posted. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this. If you aggregate all the daily averages you'll get down to one row per date. From that point it's easy to use the rolling window. Note that it does assume there will be at least one row to represent every date.

```
with params as (
    select cast(<start> as date) as startDt, cast(<end> as date) as endDt
), d as (
    select
        cast("date" as date) as dt,
        case when cast("date" as date) >= startDt then 1 end as keep,
        avg(NumberValue) as average,
        count(*) as weight 
    from T cross apply (select * from params) p
    where cast("date" as date) between dateadd(day, -13, startDt) and endDt
    group by cast("date" as date)
)
select dt,
    avg(average * weight)
        over (order by dt rows between 13 preceding and current row)
from d
where keep = 1;
```