# MS SQL - How to have dynamic query of OPENQUERY in sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I have to create a view querying AD group using OpenQuery. I have [gone through this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery) but this doesn't work in case of an SQL view since we can't have local variables in a view.

Please see my below view query:

```
SELECT 
    emp.PersonnelID
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(
        MyLinkerServer, 
        'SELECT 
            sAMAccountName 
        FROM 
            ''LDAP://DC=**domain**,DC=organisation,DC=com''
        WHERE 
            objectCategory = ''Person'' AND
            objectClass = ''user'' AND
            memberOf = ''CN=ADGroupName,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=**domain**,DC=organisation,DC=com'' '
    ) a
    INNER JOIN Employee emp ON 
        emp.Alias = a.sAMAccountName
```

I want to replace `domain` by fetching it from another table called `config` which has columns - `key` and `value`. I should be able to select value passing a key and that value should replace `domain`

Comment: Is it a strict requirement to have this in a view? A stored procedure/function won't do? The reason I'm asking is because the only option to do this (AFAICT) is to write a dynamic query. You can't use a dynamic query in a view.

Comment: I discussed same with my solution architect. Use of view is no longer required, we are going to create Stored Procedure. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!