# Filter records from an OpenQuery Result

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am querying a linked server:

```
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max);
    SET @Sql = N'
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY(DATABASE_' + UPPER(@Environment) + ', ''
        Complex Query against the linked server...
    '');'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @result OUTPUT
```

Before inserting the results into the correct table I have to filter some rows of the results. I can't filter them in the original query because the results must be matched against values in the target table.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable 
SELECT * FROM @result AS r
WHERE r.Col1 NOT IN (SELECT Col1 FROM targetTable)
AND   r.Col2 NOT IN (SELECT Col2 FROM targetTable)
```

I can't use the `@results` variable to query from because it's no table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with a hint form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery)

Code:

```
DECLARE @linkedServer varchar(50) = 'linkedServerName';
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName].[Schema].[Table]
SELECT 
    t1.Column1
FROM OPENQUERY(' + @linkedServer + ', 
''
   complex query here
) AS t1

WHERE t1.Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column1 FROM [DatabaseName].[Schema].[Table])
;
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Works like a charm.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable or temporary table.  Insert the records from your openquery.  Here is an example with a table variable.

```
declare @tableVar as table (
field1 varchar(10)
, field2 int
etc
);

declare @sql as nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '
SELECT value1, value2, etc 
FROM OPENQUERY(DATABASE_' + UPPER(@Environment) + ', ''
    Complex Query against the linked server...
'');

insert into @tableVar
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Are you sure about the "EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql" within the @sql variable?
I put it outside but I get "Must declare the table variable '@tmpTable'." if I try to query "SELECT * FROM @tmpTable;".