# Pass the parameters from current database to linked database server using linked database server

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to write an select query using OPENQUERY in SQL server where  i have to select the records from linked server but in where clause i have  to compare the dates but the date should be from a table present in current DB not in linked server DB.
For example:
Select * from OPENQUERY(Linked_Server,'select * from db.table_name where Edate>(select edate from CurrentDB)')

so please help me how in can pass the parameters from current Database server to linked Database server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [including parameters in OPENQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery)

Answer (score 0):

Hiii its not necessary to use OPENQUERY
you can query in this way

```
select * from "linkservername"."DB NAME"."Tablename" where Edate > (select edate from CurrentDB)
```

try this.

Comment: hello Thanks for your reply! but it is taking too much time AFTER removing OPENQUERY

Comment: select * from "linkservername"."DB NAME"."Tablename" WITH(NOLOCK) where Edate > (select edate from CurrentDB)

Comment: try this hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find different ways to do it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query

So, for example, in your case it can be smth like this:

```
    declare @dt char(8) = (select convert(char(8), edate, 112) from CurrentDB)  -- this should return 1 value only of date type

    declare @sql varchar(4000) =
    'select *
    from openquery(MyLinkedServer, ''select * from db.table_name where Edate>''''' + @dt + ''''''')';
    exec(@sql);
```