# Exec stored procedure with OpenQuery & parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stored procedure as below. It is using a linked server to Oracle.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SVOPS_ZsmartPaymentView]
    (@param01 VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY(ZSMART_PROD, 'SELECT BANK_SN FROM CC.V_PAYMENT WHERE BANK_SN=''@param01''')
END
```

If I call the stored procedure with parameters as shown below, the result is empty:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SVOPS_ZsmartPaymentView] @param01 = 'T131612073600'
```

But if I run the statement directly like below, there is result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery(ZSMART_PROD, 'SELECT * FROM CC.V_PAYMENT WHERE BANK_SN=''T131612073600''')
```

Any idea why it returned empty result if executed using the stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery

Comment: @Peeyush, it is understandable that you are eager to contribute (and gain credits), but this is **DEFINITELY NOT**  a _possible duplicate_.

Comment: @FDavidov if you please read the question in link carefully, you will find that the answer to the linked question solves the actual question. If I wanted credits I would have answered instead of commenting with the link. (Check the Pass Basic Values part of the answer of the linked question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SVOPS_ZsmartPaymentView]
    (@param01 VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY(ZSMART_PROD, 'SELECT BANK_SN FROM CC.V_PAYMENT WHERE BANK_SN=''' + @param01 + '''')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow the sample from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query.

And it works.

**Pass Basic Values**

*When the basic Transact-SQL statement is known, but you have to pass in one or more specific values, use code that is similar to the following sample:*

> DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2) SELECT  @VAR = 'CA' SELECT 
>   @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM
>   pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')' EXEC (@TSQL)

Thanks.