# SQL Server : issue to concat parameter in a query with double openquery

Tags: sql-server, parameters, openquery

I edit a query which contains a double `openquery`. But in this query, I need to add a parameter. Because I never worked on SQL Server, I don't know how add this parameter to my query.

The query look like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery([1STCONNECTOR],'
    SELECT * 
    FROM openquery([2NDCONNECTOR],''
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE field = ''''PARAM'''''
    )'
)
```

First, I tried :

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery([1STCONNECTOR],'
    SELECT * 
    FROM openquery([2NDCONNECTOR],''
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE field = ''''' + @PARAM + '''''
    )'
)
```

But it doesn't work.

Then, I tried to separate the query like :

```
SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field = ' + @PARAM + ')'

SELECT * 
FROM openquery([1STCONNECTOR],'
    SELECT * 
    FROM openquery([2NDCONNECTOR],'''+ @VAR +''')')
```

But it also doesn't work.

The errors returned are about the syntax like :

`Unexpected "+", expected ")"`

Another attempt which looks like the previous :

```
SET @query1 = 'SELECT * FROM openquery([2NDCONNECTOR],' + @query2 + ')' 

SET @query2 = 'SELECT * from BPCS61F.ITH WHERE field = ' + @PARAM + ')'

SELECT * FROM openquery([1STCONNECTOR], @query1)
```

Here, the error is on the third query, and say :

`Syntax error close of "@query1". Expected STRING, or TEXT_LEX`

`@query1` and `@query2` are both `varchar(max)`

Sorry if the syntax don't respect the conventions of SQL server language, I'm learning.

Thank you,
Saul

Comment: can you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery