# Incorrect Syntax using quotes in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to make this SQL query into a stored procedure. I have this code I want to use to fetch values for currency. It does not work as expected.

The code looks something like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowVaultBalances
    @SOL_ID varchar(50) = NULL,
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50) = NULL
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer_Name,
                   'select foracid, acct_name, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt from table_name where bacid = ''1010000001'' and acct_crncy_code = ' + @acct_crncy_code + ' and sol_id = ' + @SOL_ID + '')
END
```

And get this error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ShowVaultBalances, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? The same code will not run on both.

Comment: SQL server , its a Linked Server. which is Linked from Oracle to SQL server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [including parameters in OPENQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery)

Answer (score 1):

OPENQUERY doesn't support string concatenation. You have to use Dynamic SQL for the full statement.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowVaultBalances
    @SOL_ID varchar(50) = NULL,
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50) = NULL
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer_Name,
                   ''select foracid
                   , acct_name
                   , acct_crncy_code
                   , clr_bal_amt 
                   from table_name 
                   where bacid = ''''1010000001'''' 
                   and acct_crncy_code = ''''' + QUOTENAME(@acct_crncy_code,'''') + ''''' 
                   and sol_id = ''''' + QUOTENAME(@SOL_ID,'''') + ''''''')'
    
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

Comment: Err you did not add this SOL_ID and acct_crncy_code, wont i be needing those too?

Comment: This is, however, wide open to injection.

Comment: @Larnu I Agree, SQL string concattenation should be avoided at all times, but sadly we don't have a parameter option for `OPENQUERY` and calling the linked server without open query can sometimes result in very bad performance. I'm open for other solutions

Comment: Which is why `QUOTENAME`/`REPLACE` is important when injecting, @PrebenHuybrechts .

Comment: Added the `QUOTENAME` My bad, thought they where in OP's question

Comment: complains seriously, says Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near 'NGN'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Comment: Updated, i've missed some escape quotes

Comment: This is correct, but here is a more complete answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery