# T-SQL Openquery with list parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I would like to know how to pass a list into `openquery`. To use a single value the following will work:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)

SELECT @VAR = 'CA'
SELECT @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'

EXEC (@TSQL)
```

[including parameters in OPENQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery)

However, I need to be able to use a condition like

```
WHERE state IN ('CA', 'TX', 'SD')
```

rather than `= 'CA'`. I have tried many things with no luck. Help is appreciated.

I tried to use the below solution but it failed.

```
DECLARE @list NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @list = 'value1, value2, value3' -- Replace this with your list of values

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = '
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([YourLinkedServerName], 
    ''SELECT * 
      FROM YourRemoteTable 
      WHERE YourColumn IN (''' + REPLACE(@list, ',', ''',''') + ''')''
    )'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: do a `PRINT @sql` and verify the query

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `PRINT @sql`, you will see that the dynamic query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([YourLinkedServerName], 
    'SELECT * 
      FROM YourRemoteTable 
      WHERE YourColumn IN ('value1',' value2',' value3')'
    )
```

which is wrong. You will need to double the single quote in the dynamic query

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([YourLinkedServerName], 
    'SELECT * 
      FROM YourRemoteTable 
      WHERE YourColumn IN (''value1'','' value2'','' value3'')'
    )
```

So when forming `@sql`, it should be

```
IN (''''' + REPLACE(@list, ',', ''''',''''') + ''''')''
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the *real* question is why are you using `OPENQUERY` in the first place?

You can query the Linked Server directly using four-part naming, no dynamic SQL needed.

```sql
DECLARE @VAR char(2) = 'CA';

SELECT a.*
FROM MyLinkedServer.pubs.dbo.authors a
WHERE a.state = @VAR;
```

For a list, you can use a table variable, a temp table or a TVP.

```sql
DECLARE @list TABLE (value char(2));
INSERT @list VALUES ('v1'), ('v2'), ('v3');

SELECT a.*
FROM MyLinkedServer.pubs.dbo.authors a
WHERE a.state IN (SELECT * FROM @VAR);
```

Comment: Sometimes sql server cannot push the WHERE into the linked server if four part naming is used. At least that might be one of the reasons. Also, some providers (read lazy driver developers) don't even support four part names due to ... reasons

Comment: @siggemannen I think then you can just do `MyLinkedServer.pubs..authors`. Why would the `WHERE` not be passed through?